# 30th problem of the fifth book of Diophantus;

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Is there a complete answer to this problem? I have found Saunderson's answer, but I believe it is missing a few answers. The problem states:

$a^2+b^2=d^2 \\
a^2+c^2=e^2 \\
b^2+c^2=f^2$

Saunderson proves the answer is

$a=y(4x^2-z^2)\\
b=x(4y^2-z^2)\\
c=4xyz$

where $x,y,z$ is the Pythagorean triple $x^2+y^2=z^2$. But this skips answers like $(85,132,720)$,$(132,351,720)$, etc.

The complete Saunderson proof is here:
https://play.google.com/books/reader?id=1NI_AQAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover&output=reader&hl=en&pg=GBS.PA429

The solutions are also known as Euler Bricks.

Also (since I don't think a complete answer exists), *do any of you have suggestions on how to find one?*

Comment: Is it easy to see that your examples aren't covered by Saunderson's formulas?

Comment: Depends what you mean by easy to see. I run programs, and that is how I know.

Answer (score 3):

The [four smallest Euler bricks](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~knill/various/eulercuboid/lecture.pdf) are,

$$44, 117, 240$$

$$85, \color{brown}{132}, \color{brown}{720}$$

$$88, 234, 480$$

$$\color{brown}{132}, 351, \color{brown}{720}$$

Notice that the second and fourth bricks share two terms.  There are an infinite number of such Euler brick pairs.  Let $u^2+v^2 = 5w^2$, then,

$$a,b = (u^2-w^2)(v^2-w^2),\;  4uvw^2$$

and

$$c = 2uw(v^2-w^2)\;\;\color{brown}{or}\;\; 2vw(u^2-w^2)$$

This is a [second parameterization](https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/0021) in terms of quadratic forms. Bremner in "[The Rational Cuboid and a Quartic Surface](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.rmjm/1250126291)" showed there are *many, many* identities. As Bremner points out in the last page, *"...there will be a rational parametrization of every even degree greater than or equal to six..."*.

It is then doubtful there is a single polynomial identity that covers all solutions.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions about how to go about covering all solutions?